# Android-App Verzögerung ohne groß drum-herum

Tags: android

Ich habe versucht eine einfache Verzögerung für folgendes Szenario zu finden:

Ich habe in einer Android-App eine Passwortabfrage zusammengebastelt, bei der, wenn das Passwort 3-mal falsch eingegeben wurde, eine Wartezeit von 60 Sekunden ansteht.
Und diese Wartezeit soll auf einem
`TextView` optisch angezeigt werden.
Der relevante Ausschnitt, den ich dazu schon habe:

```
public void waitAMinute()
{
Integer WaitSeconds = 60;
while(WaitSeconds > 0)
{
//Wait 1 Second
WaitSeconds --;
}
}
```

Natürlich wird die Methode `WaitAMinute` auch aufgerufen.
Ich suche jetzt eine Möglichkeit, die Sekunde abzuwarten, **Ohne** `Thread.sleep()` oder `wait()` zu verwenden, da `wait()` nicht richtig funktioniert und `Thread.sleep()` den ganzen `Thread` anhält und so auch keine Bildschirmaktualisierung stattfindet...

Ich hoffe, mir kann jemand helfen!

Comment: Please post your question in English

Comment: Kümmere mich drum